# Finding center of point layer in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: python, arcgis-pro, global-scene

I have a point layer that has Lat/long coordinates. How to find the center of a given point layer. For more understanding, I attached a drawing.

How is it possible to do this?

[image]

I tried to use the tools "Mean center", "FeatureToPoint", but they give false results and find exactly not the center, can there be other tools or can you somehow find it using python, I have an attribute table that contains only the lat/long coordinates (-180 :180) (-90: 90). Maybe you can use some formulas?

Comment: Do you already know how to get your red "oval"?  If not, I think that should be the question that you ask.  Once you have the "oval" as a polygon obtaining its centroid is easy.

Comment: well, to make this oval, I thought you need to go through a double cycle, each time changing the latitude and longitude and write down the values that will coincide with the points of the outskirts.

Comment: Have a go at the [mean centre tool](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/spatial-statistics/mean-center.htm)? Not sure how it will deal with polar coordinate system though.

Comment: I tried this tool, it calculates the center somehow incorrectly.

Comment: if you build a raster or a closed circle based on these points, what tools are there to find the center?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculating area in ArcGIS Pro Global Scene](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/387719/calculating-area-in-arcgis-pro-global-scene)

Comment: no. this answer not my question